# Codimension of subvarieties is subadditive

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Assume $X$ is an irreducible affine variety and $Y_1,\ldots,Y_k$ irreducible affine subvarieties such that $Y := \bigcap_{i=1}^k Y_i \neq \emptyset$. Then Shafaferich Chapter 1 mentions the following fact.

$$ \mathrm{codim}_X(Y) \leq \sum_{i=1}^k\mathrm{codim}_X(Y_i)$$

where $\mathrm{codim}_X(Z)$ for a subvariety $Z$ of $X$ is defined to be $\dim(X) - \dim(Z).$ We can also write the above equivalently as

$$ \mathrm{dim}(Y) \geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^k \dim(Y_i)\right) - (k-1)\dim(X).$$

Shafarevich gives the proof of the above fact in the case that $X= \mathbb{A}^N$ but does not prove this in general. (In general, his proof shows that  if $X$ is a closed subvariety of $\mathbb{A}^N$, then $\dim(Y) \geq \sum_{i=1}^k \dim(Y_i)  - (k-1)N$. This is a weaker statement.) Is there a simple way of proving this via a reduction to the case when $X= \mathbb{A}^N$? Or perhaps in a similar way?

Consider the case $k=2$. One way I tried to approach this question was to consider the finite map $\varphi:X\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^d$ given by Noether Normalization, where $d = \dim(X).$ As finite maps are closed, it follows that $\varphi(Y_1)$ and $\varphi(Y_2)$ are closed subvarieties of $\mathbb{A}^d$ and hence that $\varphi(Y_1)\cap \varphi(Y_2)$ has dimension $\dim(Y_1) + \dim(Y_2) - d$. However, it is not clear (and probably untrue) that $\varphi(Y) = \varphi(Y_1)\cap \varphi(Y_2).$

Comment: Perhaps https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0AZP may help.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer: Thanks for your comment. The reference you supplied uses material about schemes that I'm unfamiliar with. Do you know of a reference that is more elementary (say at the level of Shafarevich chapter 1 and 2?)